# Are there any parallel issues with Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
if (maxLength>=0 && (++totalLength > maxLength))
    throw new IllegalStateException("Form too large");
```

in a loop where bytes are read from byte array input stream. The `maxLength` is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so I think that the condition could never be true (and I'm not talking about the size of the byte array in input stream which I'm absolutely sure is not long enough). But I get the `IllegalStateException` thrown from that line!!! Now the real bummer is that when I put a breakpoint on that throw line, everything is ok. How the hell is this possible?

**EDIT**:

- both variables are of type int
- totalLength is a local variable, maxLength is a parameter
- the debugger don't stop there AND the exception is not thrown at all, when there is a breakpoint on that throw line.
- I actualy don't know why I'm suspecting parallelism, it's just because it's web application
- I admit that using MAX_VALUE is very risky (in the next step I will try to decrease this limit), but I would expect some other execption than that in the success branch of if statement. And moreover that byte array used in input stream is really not long enough. This should be plainly impossible situation in JVM:-).
- The code above is in jetty-util-7.1.5.v20100705.jar in the class UrlEncoded and I'm using it by calling

  ```
  byte[] decodedBytes;
  byte[] encodedBytes;

  // v pripade url encoded requestu je potreba pouze odriznout
  // jmeno falesneho parametru nesouciho kodovany blok
  encodedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(content, "encdata=".length(), content.length);
  decodedBytes = decodeBytes(request, encodedBytes);

  // priprav desifrovany text jako vstupni proud
  decodedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);

  // pokud je request url encoded je potreba jej manualne parsovat
  // pro potreby funkci vracejicich parametry
  UrlEncoded.decodeTo(decodedInputStream, parameters, request.getCharacterEncoding(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  ```

Comment: Please post your exception stacktrace and more of your code with line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> **Are there any parallel issues with Integer.MAX_VALUE**

No, this is most likely not due to any race-conditions (unless you have other threads modifying `maxLength` or so).

According to the JLS on integer is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so this is either due to a bug in your VM or based on the false assumption that `maxLength` is indeed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

> **The maxLength is set to Integer.MAX_VALUE so I think that the condition could never be true**

Make sure `totalLength` is not a `long`.

(The snippet below always throws the exception.)

```
int maxLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

long totalLength = 2147483647;

if (maxLength>=0 && (++totalLength > maxLength))
    throw new IllegalStateException("Form too large");
```

If it's not reproducible with the debugger, just give a more informative error message to the exception, for instance: `"Form too large: " + totalLength + " is larger than " + maxLength`

Comment: +1 for **If it's not reproducible with the debugger, just give a more informative error message to the exception, for instance: "Form too large: " + totalLength**. You should output maxLength there, too, to avoid the problem being that this is changed here.

Comment: Agreed. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to increment totalLength before the comparison, rather than after? If your totalLength going into that statement is equal to maxLength, the exception will be thrown... is that a possible scenario?

Try totalLength++ instead.

Just a thought. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, if `totalLength` is of type `int` your comment is not true.

Comment: As [this example](http://ideone.com/0BdNd) shows, it doesn't matter if you do `++totalLength` or `totalLength++`. In won't throw in either case.

Comment: You do realize that in the (now updated) code above, totalLength is numerically equal to the max int value... and if I remember right wont the maxLength be upcast to a long for comparison since totalLength is a long? If you put ++ after totalLength it will do the comparison before incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the real bummer is that when I put a breakpoint on that throw line, everything is ok

Do you mean the debugger doesn't stop there?

From your question title it seems you suspect a racing condition (multithreading) issue.
How are the variables defined?
Could you post some more code?

Could maxLength be modified elsewhere? Or is it final?